# Cache shop with other variables Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How I can cache my shop show in controller, I have method:

```
    public function showShop(Shop $shop) {
        views($shop)->record();

        $views = views($shop)->unique()->count();

         $shop = Cache::remember('shop-' . $shop->id, 30, function () use 
         ($shop) {
            return $shop;
         });

         return view('shop.show', compact('shop', 'views'));
   }
```

In this example, I cache only `$shop`, how I can cache views record and variable `$views`. If I paste:

```
 views($shop)->record();

 $views = views($shop)->unique()->count();
```

in body of cache.

Then I can't get views in compact method. How I can cache my shop correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest looking at [Spatie response cache package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache) if you want to cache the page response.